# ArcGIS - Flow Direction (Algorithm)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, algorithm, hydrology, flow-direction

I am curious about the algorithm of Flow Direction in ArcGIS. Recently I am studying about Hidrology, and I have some questions regard to Flow Direction in GIS.

The size of this cell is 100m x 100m, with the radius of 10km for the raster data model. I have used the Flow Direction. The result showed that the value of one circle is 1. I am curious about this result.[image]

1. Since the value of the circle is same, how the Flow Direction result could came out like that?
2. what kind of logarithm is that? I have tried to find the answer in here: (http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000052000000.htm). But I still cannot understand. Would you explain it to me?
3. Using DEM, finally i got this value. But my question is : what kind of Flow Direction is this? ([16]West? or [4]South)
   [image]

Beside of the raster data model, I have also made he square and hexagonal Flow Direction model as you can see below.

[image]

I hope you can help me to figure out my question.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but perhaps this is occurring because you have applied the algorithm to a perfectly round space. Nothing in geography is actually exactly perfectly round, and thus the algorithm works. 

Does this make sense to anyone else?

Comment: I would expect a perfectly flat surface to be all flow direction 0 (no flow) except if you use 'force' to force the flow, then it will try to do *something*. The flow direction uses the elevation of the surrounding 8 cells to approximate which way is 'down' for that cell - on a flat surface there is no up or down.

Comment: Usually flat result in one-directional flow. From help:•If a cell has the same change in z-value in multiple directions and is not part of a sink, the flow direction is assigned with a lookup table defining the most likely direction. See Greenlee (1987).